# Use notification as a toggle

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm currently developing a simple Flashlight app.
I want to have a notification which can be pressed by the user and works like a toggle for the flashlight, so the user can turn the flashlight on and off, even if the app runs in the background and isn't visible to the user.
I already experiemented a lot with notifications, but the only thing I managed to achieve was a notification that started an activity which was then brought to the foreground.
As I understand it, notifications can only launch activities. So how can I achieve that the activity stays in the background and just turns the flashlight on/off?

Comment: You can also use widget that works for On/Off.i think it will be more acceptable by the Application users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand it, notifications can only launch activities.

You are wrong. You can start a service with [PendingIntent.getService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)).

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, HandleNotificationClickService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Source: [Answer to "Start Service from Notification"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386801/4525946)

And if I understand you correctly, you probably also want to use [Builder.setOngoing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)) to keep your notification visible after click.

Comment: So I would have to implement a service to start/stop my flashlight?

Comment: Using my approach, yes. This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594251/android-camera-getparameters-crashes-app